# Go: naming convention for slice variables/params?

Tags: go

Is the convention for naming slices in Go? Specifically, do you use plurals?
I've noticed that Go App Engine doesn't (eg. it uses `key` not `keys`):

```
func GetMulti(c appengine.Context, key []*Key, dst interface{}) error
```

I haven't seen anything equivalent in the standard packages or docs I've read. Is singular or plural normal?

Comment: Maybe it's called `key` since the only usage with it is indexing and `key[0]` sounds nicer than `keys[0]` for the implementor. It doesn't change a lot either way. One of Go's principles says no consistency-to-death, but flexibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That should be a typo, I guess.

Names of slices and arrays are plural. It's not hard to find some samples in the standard library: function `SetCookies` in [`CookieJar`](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CookieJar), [`Readdirnames`](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/#File.Readdirnames), or `Args` variable in the [variables of os package](http://weekly.golang.org/pkg/os/#Variables).

But for any variable use a name that better explains its purpose.

A clear exception to this all-plural approach is `argv` which had its name for decades.

Comment: I think the exception with 'argv' is not an exception. It's a singular: 'argument vector', not 'vectors'.

Comment: Great answer +1. Would you also use a plural for other types of data set identifiers such as a `struct`? Tom

Answer (score 0):

@Mostafa is right. Names of slices and arrays in Go should be a plural. `fns` is the plural of `fn` in this example from @Ainar-G. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35648660/12817546..

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var fns []func()
    fns = append(fns, beeper)
    fns = append(fns, pinger)
    for _, fn := range fns {
        fn() //beep-beep ping-ping
    }

}
func beeper() { fmt.Println("beep-beep") }
func pinger() { fmt.Println("ping-ping") }
```

@Mostafa is also right that names should explain their purpose. To add to this, self-evident names make code more readable. Self-evident names comment on and document their code.

Self-evident names are consistent. That is they are easy to guess.`beeper` matches "beep-beep". Self-evident names are accurate. That is they are easy to understand.`fns` matches `fn` which denotes a `func`.

Self-evident names are short. That is they are easy to type. Short names require a short distance between their declaration and their use. Arguments such as `fn` can be one or two characters-long. For everything else a short one word noun can be used. But sometimes if the distance is great more explanation is needed. A multi-word name `mixedCaps` can be used. But don't use an `under_score_name`.

The names used may not be as self-evident as they could be. As a result code may have too many `//` line comments. Comments can make code less readable. Rename your identifiers so they become more self-evident. And then the number of `//` can be reduced without loss of explanation.

There are other limits to the use of names. Go keywords cannot be used. Canonical `Read`, `Write`, `Close`, `Flush`, `String` etc words should not be used. The first character of a name must be a Unicode letter or a `_`. Remember capitalized names such as `MixedCaps` can be exported and `type` identifiers are typically uppercase.

To find out more have a look at https://talks.golang.org/2014/names.slide, https://blog.golang.org/package-names, https://talks.golang.org/2013/bestpractices.slide, https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers and https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names.