# How to store functions in a slice in Go

Tags: go

I'm trying to port the following Python functionality to Golang.
Especially, how to store functions in a slice and then call them.
How can I do this in Golang?

```
class Dispatcher(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._listeners = []

    def addlistener(self, listener):
        self._listeners.append(listener)

    def notifyupdate(self):
        for f in self._listeners:
            f()

def beeper():
    print "beep...beep...beep"

def pinger():
    print "ping...ping...ping"

dispatch = Dispatcher()
dispatch.addlistener(beeper)
dispatch.addlistener(pinger)
dispatch.notifyupdate()

output:
beep...beep...beep

ping...ping...ping
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's pretty easy actually:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var fns []func()
    fns = append(fns, beeper)
    fns = append(fns, pinger)

    for _, fn := range fns {
        fn()
    }
}

func beeper() {
    fmt.Println("beep-beep")
}

func pinger() {
    fmt.Println("ping-ping")
}
```

Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/xuDsdeRQX3.

Comment: This is a concise example +1. I've quoted you here https://stackoverflow.com/a/64300628/12817546.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you want an even closer structure (admittedly, not needed, at all, in this case):

```
package main

import "fmt"

type dispatcher struct {
    listeners []func()
}

func (d *dispatcher) addListener(f func()) {
    d.listeners = append(d.listeners, f)
}

func (d *dispatcher) notify() {
    for _, f := range d.listeners {
        f()
    }
}

func ping() {
    fmt.Println("Ping... ping...")
}

func beep() {
    fmt.Println("Beep... beep...")
}

func main() {
    d := dispatcher{}
    d.addListener(ping)
    d.addListener(beep)
    d.notify()
}
```

[Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/pRPSQ7vIbj)

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var funcs = []func(){}
    funcs = append(funcs, beeper)
    funcs = append(funcs, pinger)

    for _, f := range funcs {
        f()
    }
}

func beeper() {
    fmt.Println("I'm a beeper")
}

func pinger() {
    fmt.Println("I'm a pinger")
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/PaClU6Ri4n

Answer (score 0):

```
func main(){
    var funcSlice []func()
    funcSlice = append(funcSlice, f1)
    funcSlice = append(funcSlice, f2)
}

func f1(){  
    fmt.Println("")
}

func f2(){ 
    fmt.Println("")
}
```

Comment: This answer is essentially the same as @Ainar-G. See https://play.golang.org/p/KYuCJGtkvrd.

Answer (score 0):

If you use more complexes functions you do this :

```
func addr(instru, beforeg [4]int) [4]int {
    beforeg[instru[3]] = beforeg[instru[1]] + beforeg[instru[2]]
    return beforeg
}

func addi(instru, beforeg [4]int) [4]int {
    beforeg[instru[3]] = beforeg[instru[1]] + instru[2]
    return beforeg
}

func day16Run(isTest bool) {
    arrayFunc:= [16]func([4]int, [4]int) [4]int{addr, addi}
    // use arrayFunc
}
```

And if your functions have differnt signatures, use a slice and append as you go, but be careful when calling the functions : 
[Golang - How do you create a slice of functions with different signatures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37314365/golang-how-do-you-create-a-slice-of-functions-with-different-signatures)