# Run multiple conditional function in golang

Tags: go

I would like to run workflow functions using 5 functions in golang

1. init
2. validate
3. process
4. execute
5. finalize

Each method should return the same result object and error object in case of failure

I would like to find a pattern to run this workflow rather than doing the following:

```
if result, err := init(); err != nil {
    if result, err := validate(); err != nil {
       if result, err := process(); err != nil {
           if result, err := execute(); err != nil {
               if result, err := finalize(); err != nil {

               }
           }
       }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance
Peter

Comment: Do it like that: https://play.golang.org/p/VURnlebXCO-

Comment: You can put your functions in a slice and do a `range` over it

Comment: Your code runs `validate` only if `init` fails, and `process` only if both `init` and `validate` failed, and so on. It doesn't sound like that is your intent. Tobias' example would be the idiomatic solution if your intent is to abort if a step fails.

Comment: right it should proceed just in case the previous method finished with no error

Comment: Just an extension with @TobiasTheel comment. https://play.golang.org/p/cJlGAanKDyt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a slice of functions and make this whole process prettier, e.g.

```
functions := []func() (string, error){
    function1, function2, function3, function4, function5,
}
for _, function := range functions {
    someValue, err := function()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Function " + someValue + " didn't feel so good.")
        break
    }
    fmt.Println("Function " + someValue + " went all right!")
}
```

In short, the break stops things from going on, if you wrap the above process as a function, you could also use something like

```
return false
```

in case of an error, and at the end of the total amount of iterations, say i == len(functions) -1, you could return true if everything went all right.

It is noteworthy to mention that you can only create slice of functions that satisfies these conditions:

- They all must have the same amount of arguments;
- All arguments must have the same type per position;
- They all have the same amount of return values;
- Likewise, they (return values) must have the same type per position;

Still, you can easily overcome these limitations by having two or three different slices. For example, function1 to function3 can all be classified as

```
func () (bool, err)
```

Where function4 and 5 are

```
func () (int, err)
```

For these functions to work you could just reiterate the first slice, then if everything goes as planned, move on to the second.

```
firstSetOfFuncs := []func() (bool, error){
    function1, function2, function3,
}
secondSetOfFuncs := []func() (int, err){
    function4, function5,
}
for i, function := range firstSetOfFuncs {
    someValue, err := function()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Something went terribly wrong.")
        break
    }
    if i == len(firstSetOfFuncs) - 1 {
        for _, secondTypeOfFunc := range secondSetOfFuncs {
            someNum, anotherErr := secondTypeOfFunc()
            if anotherErr != nil {
                fmt.Println("All seemed all right, until it didn't.")
                break
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also have a set of different functions (different parameter etc). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37319624/4992212) shows how. I was also about to create an example of a slice of functions, but you were faster :)

Answer (score 2):

As i allready said in a comment, i think the most [idiomatic](https://blog.golang.org/error-handling-and-go) way would be to just call a method, check for errors. And if there was an error return it. 
You can of course use the simplified error handling version, like you used in your question, but even if you do that. Try to avoid that deep [nesting](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/N/nesting.html). It's hard to read & understand (deeply) nested code.

```
result,err := init()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err // An error occured so handle it
}

result,err = validate()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}


result,err = process()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}


result,err = execute()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}

result,err = finalize()
if err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
```

### Problems of your example code

You've done the error checking wrong. You are checking for

> if err != nil

Spoken "if there is an error". And you continue with your code, although there is an error.

To fix that you need to write:

```
var result someType

if result, err := init(); err != nil {
  return nil, err // An error occured so handle it
}

if result, err := validate(); err != nil {
  return nil, err
}


if result, err := process(); err != nil {
  return nil, err
}

if result, err := execute(); err != nil {
  return nil, err
}

if result, err := finalize(); err != nil {
  return nil, err
}
```